# Why do you not use CPAN modules?

Tags: perl, cpan

ETA: When I ask "Why do you not use CPAN modules?", I am referring to the people who refuse to use **any** CPAN modules (including high quality ones like [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm)).  Not all CPAN code is of high quality, and it is fine to stay away from modules that are trivial or are based on experimental code (I got annoyed at a developer the other day for wanting to bring in [Time::Format](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Format/lib/Time/Format.pm) just because he didn't know that strftime was in [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html)).

Recently on [Perl Beginners](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/), someone want to know how to do something without resorting to the Perl module commonly suggested for that function.  He or she did not want to install the module from CPAN.  This made me think about the reasons I have seen people avoid using CPAN and I came up with five reasons for this behaviour and the solution for each one:

1. they scare you (answer, get over it)
2. they scare your sysadmins (answer, work around them by
     installing in your home directory and use the lib pragma)
3. you are using a hosting service that prevents you from
     installing modules (answer, get a better service, there
     are cheap services that don't behave like morons)
4. the target machine doesn't necessarily have the needed
     module (answer, use PAR or PAR::Packer)
5. the target machine is totally locked down (i.e. you login
     to rbash and have to provide code to a third party for
     inclusion on the box) (a combination of 4 and going through
     the bureaucracy)
6. You are using an embedded version of Perl that can't load modules (no answer, you are stuck, but this is very rare)

So, if you don't use CPAN, why, and why are the answers above not adequate?  Note, I am not asking why you don't install directly from CPAN on production boxen, I am asking why you avoid using the modules from CPAN (installing via packaging systems count as using CPAN to me).

Comment: ox -> oxen, box -> boxen.  I didn't invent this crazy language.

Comment: Fox -> foxen? Nah, it's not the crazy language's fault. I don't feel especially strongly about the plural of 'box' one way or the other, but I don't think we can blame English in this case.

Comment: Awesome! I've been worried about point 4 for a while for a text adventure I've been working on. I should have known there was a nice way to bundle everything together for distribution.

Comment: boxen: see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15422/use-of-en-suffix/15460#15460  Boxen is plural, foxen is diminutive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have the Perl scripting engine embedded in a host application (for example a webserver, or any complex application requiring scripting), and have a whole lot of restrictions in that embedded context, like not being able to load files.

Comment: Except for calling it PERL, that's a good point :)

Comment: A valid point I had missed in my original analysis, but most of those have the ability to load modules.  Most even provide the ability to load the modules once (like mod_perl).

Comment: Thanks for the capitalization fix, it made me discover both the correct spelling and the Stack Overflow feature.

Answer (score 16):

There are a few reasons that I sometimes counsel people not to use certain CPAN modules. Not all of CPAN is high-quality code, and there are varying levels of maintenance for different distributions. Everyone should consider how much work they have to do to use a particular CPAN module and what that module saves them (i.e. total cost of ownership). Using any particular CPAN module is not always a benefit. I don't say that people should not use any of CPAN, but they should consider what they really need from it.

1. An external module dependency allows someone else to break your application. The CPAN toolchain only ever cares about the latest version of a module and may upgrade your installation when it sees you have an earlier version. I've seen many applications break when the underlying external dependencies introduce new bugs, deprecated needed features, and so on. It's one of the reasons I've been developing my tools for companies to host their own CPAN repositories so they can control that. There are other ways to mitigate that, but not many people are sophisticated enough to have a good process for it.
2. You work in an environment where all code has to be approved. This seems like a silly requirement to a lot of people, but the risk management people have a job to do too. Sometimes that compliance is mandated by various laws, standards of care, and so on. Unless the module is really going to save a lot of time and energy, the benefit may not be worth the effort to go through that process. Really, how many of you ever seriously inspect the code you get from CPAN? There could be anything in there.
3. Some CPAN modules implement trivially-coded functionality. Using a module just because it's on CPAN and you don't want to write the three lines of code yourself is a bit silly. You can talk about code reuse all you like, but eventually that's *reductio ad absurdum*.
4. Installation of some modules can be quite tricky, fragile, and unpredictable, and sometimes this is due to the long list of dependencies to just build and test the module even though you don't need those dependencies to actually use the module. It takes a lot of work to handle these cases in automated testing environments.
5. Some CPAN authors are experimental coders, not maintainers. Creating dependencies on their work means you end up with an unsupported module that doesn't get patched and no one else really cares about. Getting your patches accepted is a really big deal for some important projects, and you can't fix the unresponsive author without resorting to some process for using a locally patched version and isn't overwritten by the CPAN toolchain.

You don't escape these reasons with glib answers about using another service, installing in a local directory, and so on. You can't apply your counter arguments to every situation and setup. Anyone telling you otherwise, such as the top post in [Top Seven (Bad) Reasons Not To Use Modules](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=750190) that Leon links to, isn't really thinking about anyone's situation, and there are many thoughtful counter-counter arguments.

Don't ever start from the position of thinking anyone should or shouldn't use CPAN. Evaluate the local situation, evaluate the risks and rewards, develop safeguards for the risks, and use modules wisely. That's not any different from any other sort of serious software development or business practice.

Comment: 1. PAR or PAR::Packer, 2. covered in number 5, 3. perhaps I should clarify that I am talking about useful modules like DBI, 4. is a pain I have gone through, but writing the code yourself is not really an answer either, 5. again, I should probably clarify.

Comment: You're missing the point Chas. PAR doesn't solve anything. It doesn't make bad code work. If you really want to honestly advocate your point, you seriosuly have to address all the issues. You can't pretend problems don't exist.

Comment: Yes, I am missing the point. PAR/pp removes the possibility of someone else upgrading a module on the machine breaking your code.  Which is what I thought 1 was about. And you must chose which modules you use from CPAN carefully.

Comment: Not using CPAN because there is some bad code on it is like not hiring people because there are bad coders.  I believe Sturgeon's Law applies here.

Comment: I think there may also be some confusion between CPAN the tool (that I half love and half despise) and CPAN the repository.  I don't think I have ever used CPAN the tool in production.  I prefer to use the packages my vendor creates out of modules from CPAN.  They, at least, can be backed out.

Comment: Who said anything about not using CPAN because there is some bad code on it? I think you didn't actually read what I wrote because of your kneejerk reaction. You might check out the summary in the last paragraph, for instance.

Comment: I know this is old but how do you distinguish high quality modules from not so high quality ones?

Comment: The high quality ones do what you need without breaking. The not so high quality ones don't. You get experience by trying your options and seeing which ones work for you.

Comment: As for updating breaking your code - consider using carton, which allows you to specify a version you want, or just get the latest.

Answer (score 9):

I'm glad you asked.

I was thinking of asking a question like "Why does CPAN have to suck so much?" but decided it wasn't worth sacrificing my reputation when I (think I) already know the answer. And since this question is marked "subjective" I'll thank you for not moderating me down for giving my personal take on this issue, even if you think I am mistaken or stupid.

First some background: I did quite a lot of Perl coding in the mid-nineties and enjoyed it, but eventually concluded that the language lacked a lot features that were needed for "real" object-oriented programming. I became a C++ developer for several years, and now am now a very technical project manager. I still use Perl for scripts and data crunching and other bits and pieces, and have recently started using Perl scripts to test the web services our coders have developed.

Anyway, I came to stack-overflow for the project-management, but stayed for the Perl. I'm pleased to see the language has grown up and has all sorts of fantastic module's like Moose and MVC and templates and so on, and would like to be using them... and I will. But it is taking time, and I only have a few hours now and then to work with it.  Why isn't it easy?

But to answer the question...

1. First the obvious answer: most Perl programs don't need CPAN modules.
2. There's more than one way to do it. I don't need modules to do a lot of things that I would use modules for if it was easy to do so. For example, I have been parsing XML documents with split() and regular expressions. I know it's wrong (but the first step to recovery is admitting you have a problem). But I can copy and paste the code to do this in a few seconds, or I could go away and try and make cpan work for another month or so.
3. Now lets get a little more controversial. CPAN is brittle. Earlier this year I tried to use cpan to install Moose because I had read great things about it and was keen to do proper OO programming in Perl and for it not to be hard/ugly.  So I followed the install instructions, and pressed 'Y' hundreds of time (it seemed) before getting dumped on with pages and pages of compiler warnings in the final step. What the hell do I do now? My main dev box has some sort of half-broken Moose module just waiting (I am sure) to bite me in the ass when I least expect it. That was about two months ago, and I have not been back. I speculate that lots of Perl/CPAN have dependencies on other programming languages and that makes it more brittle (as opposed to languages whose libraries are coded in the same language). I further speculate that experiences like this scare potential users off.
4. Documentation for CPAN beginners is poor. Where is the authoritative CPAN documentation anyway? Where's the introduction and tutorials for beginners? And how was I supposed to know that?  I have been reading CPAN documentation on and off for a few months, and am starting to figure out where things are. (I see that almost all individual Perl modules on CPAN are beautifully documented internally, but it took me a long time to find that documentation.)
5. The install process is too hard. Four steps and hundreds of prompts may have been okay ten years ago when there were fewer packages and fewer dependencies, but now it is just crappy. Why can't I just type something like 'cpan-install Moose' in my shell and have it be done?  This is particularly weird, given that advanced users often claim portability is a virtue, citing things like packages and PAR that I still don't get.  And why is installing locally even harder when so many people seem to want to do it?
6. There are vexing issues, like whether I should install CPAN modules with cpan or with the package management system, where advice is inconsistent. More generally: there is more than one way to do it. And when you start doing advanced Perl, you have to make decisions about how to install modules and what modules to use and where do you start? Remember you're a beginner and the documentation is kind of fragmented and the learning curve is steep. My solution has been to try and work around this by not using cpan while I read a little more.
7. Finally, advanced Perl has a very steep learning curve. Advanced Perl users apparently do not remember this and cannot see it. IMO there is a world of difference between using Perl as it was originally conceived -- as a practical extraction and reporting language with powerful regular expressions -- and using it as a modern development platform with OO and templates and MVC and all sorts of other goodies. I have yet to find a gentle, incremental path from casual Perl use to advanced Perl use.

So there you go. Apologies for the rant.

Comment: 3. wait for a vendor to package it (e.g. libmoose-perl in Ubuntu). 4. The docs are the same as all other docs: perldoc CPAN and perldoc cpan. 5. I don't have a problem with local installs, perhaps you should ask how to do it. 6. package management unless you need new features 7. Perl Beginners list

Comment: I'd be interested to hear the logic behind #1.  I have a feeling that it reflects a low opinion of what people do with Perl.

Comment: Thinking more on #1... why would a community produce and maintain a massive, volunteer code archive with distributed automated testing and automatic install if they didn't need it.  Is it just wankery on a massive scale?

Comment: Chas - I was initially waiting for packaging, but have decided to bite the bullet and manage through CPAN based on SO reading. And as noted, the documentation does seem to be all there, it's just that it's in 50 different places and it is not clear where you start?. (And 7 isn't about beginners.)

Comment: Schwern -- You're reading too much into 1. I would bet that most perl scripts are simple because that's what is needed. I know people do great things with perl. But in terms of raw number of times perl is used, the simple scripts will vastly outnumber the complex programs.

Comment: @Schwern: that most Perl programs don't use modules means that most Perl programs are performing simple tasks. I see it in most of the places that I work.

Comment: To install Moose from the command-line: `cpan Moose`.

Comment: Most of your comments about getting started are in my book _Learning Perl_, and the learning continues in the next two: _Intermediate Perl_ and _Mastering Perl_.

Comment: @ brian: to be fair, `cpan Moose` starts the configuration process that the OP disliked

Comment: The Perl Beginners list is not just for people who don't know the language; it is also a place from people moving from beginner Perl to intermediate Perl to mastering Perl.  Of course, once you start to master Perl you tend to answer more questions than you ask.

Comment: But never doubt the power of answering other people's questions to teach you something.

Comment: Brian -- Thanks, I will definitely try installing with cpan at the command line after I uninstall my broken Moose install. But it's a case in point, I only found out there *was* such a thing as a command-line cpan program the other day, I just don't get how you're supposed to know all this stuff.

Comment: Also, I will look for "Intermediate Perl" when I'm next in a decent bookshop.

Comment: Chas -- Couldn't agree more about answering other people's questions... see how much I'm learning from this one!

Comment: Brian -- It turns out I have "Learning Perl" on my bookshelf already, its a first edition from my mid-90s perl stint (no "cpan" or "module" in the index).

Comment: Telemachus: you obviously use old version of CPAN shell (or perl). New versions (starting from 5.8.8 or 5.10.0) have very good default configuration and ask questions only if reconfiguration is asked.

Comment: as to hitting `y` a hundred times, the new `cpanm` (cpanminus) is a cpan installer that uses a standard configuration set, works for most use just like you wanted (`cpanm Moose`).

Answer (score 8):

You may find [this essay](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=750190) (and its comments) interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I will include a link to that along with this list the next time I have to persuade someone that they are being foolish.

Answer (score 6):

Installing Perl modules locally is a tad challenging.  Here's my process:

Setup user-localized CPAN config:

```
mkdir -p ~/.cpan/CPAN
touch ~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm
```

If CPAN was previously setup for site-wide admin (meaning, you're on your own box and already fired up and configured CPAN), you can change to user-local by: "`perl -MCPAN -e mkmyconfig`".  Then, edit "`~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`":

```
'makepl_arg' => q[LIB=/home/your_name/perllib],
```

Otherwise, you can startup CPAN normally: "`perl -MCPAN -e shell`" or simply "`cpan`".  You'll be prompted for configuration.  At the "Parameters for the 'perl Makefile.PL' command?", Enter: "`PREFIX=~ LIB=~/lib/perl5`".

To reference locally installed modules in your Perl scripts, you can do the `use lib` pragma, but I think it's an annoying dependency when you have numerous perl scripts and modules to update in your app.  This is more of a workaround.

Instead, I can set the environment var `PERL5LIB` to the path where the module was installed locally, like "`$HOME/lib/perl5`".  To set `PERL5LIB` for a CGI environment, figure out how to set environment variables in the server configuration.  In Apache, I can do that in `httpd.conf` or in `.htaccess` using mod_env. (thanks, brian d foy)

Comment: The latest cpan command (found in App::Cpan) has a -j switch to load a custom configuration file that you can put anywhere you like.

Comment: To set PERL5LIB for a CGI environment, figure out how to set environment variables in the server configuration. In Apache, I can do that in the main server config or in .htaccess using the mod_env stuff.

Comment: I recently benefited from some similar advice at http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Using_Cpan_Without_Root_(Perl)

Answer (score 5):

If things "scare sysadmins" enough, they don't want you to put them *on* the machine, regardless of where it is you think you'll put them. Shops have standards for a reason.

There is no distribution of liability with a CPAN module. In the shop I currently work in, we have such a deal with our encapsulated accounting software provider. We call them in the middle of the night if our app is down and we need their expertise. Because if our calculations mess up badly enough, our contract with them ensures that *they* will be paying part of the bill, depending on their exposure with a given issue.

When you get out into the real world, where Perl scripts can run alongside 40-year old established, crusty, COBOL, you may understand how much more at ease managers are with running the COBOL than they are with "scripts" depending heavily on ardent hobbyists, however clever.

That said, my current shop is somewhat comfortable with Perl for non-critical scripts and reports, and will install the occasional CPAN module, but the approval process is rigorous, the sandbox testing is long (and expensive!), but makes it possible. I can only imagine that they could approve one or two new modules, not 50+ new modules, because of how many new situations it would expose them to. So the modules created by the "Let's just use CPAN" crowd are pretty much out if any dependency says "Not recommended for production code" or "experimental".

Comment: Not every module on CPAN is a gem, and you should definitely examine each one carefully.  I am talking about people who are afraid to install modules like the DBI.  Their fear is based on their lack of knowledge, not any real danger.

Comment: Oh! DBI? We use that. Well it's a sliding scale. Before our application established it, my company saw perl itself as a not-for-production language. But I understand the business-manager perspective, despite being a Perl "fanboy".

Comment: There are admins who are afraid to install DBI.  They cite all sorts of security BS, but really they just don't know how to install modules and don't want to learn.  I usually wind up getting a security exception to install it in the production users home directory.

Comment: Of course, on systems with real package management it is easier.  I can usually just hand an RPM or DEB to the admins and they install it like any other software without throwing any hissy fits.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one valid reason I can think of: you want to figure out how to do it yourself.  Which is fine, as long as you realize a production environment isn't for your own personal experiments.

One might say "well look at how the CPAN module does it" but reading someone else's implementation is a poor substitute for doing it yourself.  And honestly a lot of CPAN implementations are kind of terrifying.  This might be disparaging on CPAN code quality, but its also a success story on just how well encapsulated and tested a CPAN module is that for the most part you don't notice.

As to all the answers which are variations on "the CPAN shell is hard to set up", I agree.  However, this is an O(1) problem.  You solve it once and then you get easy access to CPAN for the rest of your life.

Comment: Yeah, but installing some modules is O(n) where n is the number of dependencies.  Devel::REPL was a pain in my tuckus, I had to hand install a few modules to get it to pass its tests without errors.  I probably should have kept notes and sent patches, but I was little l lazy.

Comment: Chas. Owens: Fill bug reports or at least use CPAN::Reporter - it sends installation reports automatically. Only part of authors use them, but they who use are usually most responsive so bug will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the modules are based on open source libraries and do not compile or behave well across all the nutty environments that you have.  Consider for example needing to run on NCR, HP, SUN, Linux, and AIX.

Comment: http://www.mccormick-cr.com/web/pageDetail.aspx?pgID=productsServersIndex.html sad but true...

Comment: Ah, point of sale stuff, that explains why I had no idea what it is.

Comment: were you trying to differentiate between using CPAN modules vs. not using CPAN modules or diffentiate between using the CPAN module itself to build CPAN modules... that sounds retarded... just like I used make to make make make better.  Sigh...

Answer (score 3):

> the target machine doesn't necessarily have the needed module

This can be valid in some environments. One of my friends works at a huge mega conglomerate spanning countries and continents. Frequently, he uses perl to make tape drives do things all over the world. The scripts must be deployed on literally thousands of machines and installing modules is a really big deal -- usually involving a committee and multiple sysadmins at each physical location. He tends to avoid them at all costs and I can't say I blame him.

Is there a solution for that? I really don't think there is.

(This above is a cut and paste from my answer to a really similar question on permonks.)

http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=750387

> (answer, use PAR or PAR::Packer)

I did suggest PAR to him once, but it wasn't practical at all.  None of the machines are similar enough for PAR to really be useful in a general case.  His options were: don't use modules or maintain 1300 PAR binaries.  PAR is pretty hard to get working really well even when you definitely know the target patform, so he elected to not use modules.

Comment: What problems have you had with PAR?  1300 sounds awfully high.  You do realize the build and run environments don't have to be identical right?

Comment: I don't have problems with PAR, but I'm a devoted perl nerd.  Talk to someone less perl-y and you won't hear the same story.  1300 may be high, but when we're talking about literally thousands of servers, some win32, some solaris, some hpux, all different versions, well, ...  it'll be more than 5.

Answer (score 2):

The target host has an awkward operating system that is not well supported by CPAN modules (due in part to the lack of [CPAN Testers](http://www.cpantesters.org/)).

Such examples are AIX and HP-UX. They have an old perl, either no C compiler or an old/broken one and old/broken libraries, so too many XS modules fail to install out of the box. Patching them takes time (especially when the CPAN author is not responding for months), and trying to workaround XS modules is not possible in practice (well, if you really want to go that way you'll have too often to patch pure perl modules that rely on XS modules).

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer with the positive approach, i.e. it says how you can fix the restrictions keeping you from using CPAN modules: [Yes, even you can use CPAN](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.